# prove that C = (C \D)∪(C ∩D).

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let C and D be sets. Use element chasing to prove that C = (C \D)∪(C ∩D). We can only use deﬁnitions and logical deduction. You can not use properties of sets. I am having trouble figuring out where to start on this proof. I know for element chase we have to do a case by case proof.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Assume $x\in (C\setminus D)\cup (C\cap D)$.  Show $x\in C$.  And vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C = \varnothing$ you are done. If $C \neq \varnothing$, pick an element of $C$, let's say, $c$. Now, note that, $c$ satisfy one, and only one, of the following two conditions:

- $c$ is an element of $D$,
- $c$ is not an element of $D$.

If $c$ satisfies the first, we then have that $c \in C \cap D$, and hence $c \in (C \setminus D) \cup (C \cap D)$. In the other case, we have that $c \in C \setminus D$ and again, $c \in (C \setminus D) \cup (C \cap D)$.

In either case, we see that $c \in (C \setminus D) \cup (C \cap D)$, showing that any element of $C$ is also an element of $(C \setminus D) \cup (C \cap D)$. So, $C \subseteq (C \setminus D) \cup (C \cap D)$.

Can you show the other inclusion?